# How to find If array of objects includes an element in javascript? and How to access it if includes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I find if an array of objects includes an element?

Suppose code is

```
var searchEngines = [{
    name: 'google',
    link: 'https://google.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'bing',
    link: 'https://bing.com'
  }];

//now I want to check if bing includes in array searchEngines or not (below code is wrong, please correct it)
console.log(searchEngines.name.includes('bing'));
//must return true. but it doesn't say true instead gives me an error and crashes the app.
```

so how can I check if `searchEngines` array includes bing or not?
Now if successfully checked that bing is included in `searchEngines` array, now how can I access bing?

like I wanna get the index number of bing array inside `searchEngines` array and then grab the link of it and console.log it, so I'll get `https://bing.com`

Comment: share your tried code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will return `undefined` if no item which matches the condition is found.

You can use it to find the first item whose `name` property is `'bing'`. To check whether an item was found, coerce it to a boolean and check whether it is `true`. If so, the item exists, and you can access it:

```js
var searchEngines = [{
    name: 'google',
    link: 'https://google.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'bing',
    link: 'https://bing.com'
  }
];

const includesBing = searchEngines.find(e => e.name == 'bing')

if(includesBing){
  // bing exists
  console.log(includesBing.link)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in this line `console.log(searchEngines.name.includes('bing'));`, you're trying to access the name property of the `searchEngines` variable which is an array.

I think a better way to find whether the array includes an object with the name variable set to 'bing' would be to use the `find()` function.

Here's an example:

```js
var searchEngines = [{
    name: 'google',
    link: 'https://google.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'bing',
    link: 'https://bing.com'
  }];
  
const includesBing = searchEngines.find(se => se.name === 'bing') !== undefined;
const includesYahoo = searchEngines.find(se => se.name === 'yahoo') !== undefined;

console.log(includesBing)
console.log(includesYahoo)
```

Answer (score 1):

`searchEngines.name.includes('bing')` throws an error because `searchEngines` is an array and therefore has no `name` property.

You had the right idea though, you just need to use the `map` method to get a list of just the names, rather than a list of objects, and then use `includes` to test that.

```js
var searchEngines = [{
    name: 'google',
    link: 'https://google.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'bing',
    link: 'https://bing.com'
  }];

const searchEngineNames = searchEngines.map(engine => engine.name);

console.log(searchEngineNames.includes('bing'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var searchEngines = [{
    name: 'google',
    link: 'https://google.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'bing',
    link: 'https://bing.com'
  }];
  
const searchFn = (arr, prop, searchVal) => arr.findIndex(x => x[prop]==searchVal);

// search by name
const searchName = 'bing';
const index = searchFn(searchEngines, 'name', searchName);
if(index!=-1){
  console.log(searchEngines[index].link)
}

// search by link
const searchLink = 'https://google.com';
const index2 = searchFn(searchEngines, 'link', searchLink);
if(index2!=-1){
  console.log(searchEngines[index2].name)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally like simple solutions that also work for older versions.

```
var searchEngines = [{
    name: 'google',
    link: 'https://google.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'bing',
    link: 'https://bing.com'
  }];

function itemExists(propName, searchValue) {
    for (var i in searchEngines) {
        if (searchEngines[i][propName] === searchValue) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log("containes 'bing': " + itemExists("name", "bing"));
```